# how to make a grid with the local space Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am gridding around an object but I need the grid to align in the local space of the pivot object

the code that i have

```
private void createColum()
{
    for (int i =0; i<gridGame.Count;i++)
    {
        if(gridGame[i] == gridGame[0])
        {
            gridGame[i].localPosition = gridGame[0].localPosition;
        }
        if(gridGame[i]!= gridGame[0])
        {
            
             gridGame[i].localPosition = new Vector3(gridGame[i-1].localPosition.x + distX,gridGame[0].localPosition.y, gridGame[0].localPosition.z); 
           
        }

        if(i +1 > limiteFila)
        {
            if(i%limiteFila==0)
            {
                gridGame[i].localPosition = new Vector3(gridGame[0].position.x, gridGame[0].position.y , gridGame[i-Mathf.RoundToInt(limiteFila)].position.z + distY);
            }else
            {
                 gridGame[i].position = new Vector3(gridGame[i-1].position.x + distX, gridGame[0].position.y , gridGame[i-1].position.z);
            }
            
        }
       
       gridGame[i].rotation = gridGame[0].rotation;
        
    }
}
```

with this the grid of objects is formed but only in taking the world space

[picture of how you are at this moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kziz6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but you can turn the grid into a child object and leave the worldPositionStays as false, to do so use the `SetParent(Transform parent, bool worldPositionStays)`. For example as a reference for your script.

```
private void createColum()
{
for (int i =0; i<gridGame.Count;i++)
{
    if(gridGame[i] == gridGame[0])
    {
        gridGame[i].localPosition = gridGame[0].localPosition;
        gridGame[i].transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);
    }
    if(gridGame[i]!= gridGame[0])
    {
        
         gridGame[i].localPosition = new Vector3(gridGame[i-1].localPosition.x + distX,gridGame[0].localPosition.y, gridGame[0].localPosition.z); 
       
    }

    if(i +1 > limiteFila)
    {
        if(i%limiteFila==0)
        {
            gridGame[i].localPosition = new Vector3(gridGame[0].position.x, gridGame[0].position.y , gridGame[i-Mathf.RoundToInt(limiteFila)].position.z + distY);
        }else
        {
             gridGame[i].position = new Vector3(gridGame[i-1].position.x + distX, gridGame[0].position.y , gridGame[i-1].position.z);
        }
        
    }
   
   gridGame[i].rotation = gridGame[0].rotation;
    
   }
}
```